# 16.04: How to access new disk just added

Tags: partitioning, disk-management

hardware Dell R330 running ubuntu 16.04

I have just added a new disk to this box and done a power cycle.  I can see the disk in [iDRAC](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln129295/dell-poweredge-how-to-configure-the-idrac-system-management-options-on-servers?lang=en) where it shows as "ready" but I can not see it from the OS (nothing in /dev/sd? or sudo lshw -C disk or rescan-scsi-bus) so I can not figure out how to set it up and mount it.

All the instructions I can find start with the /dev/sdx.

Comment: iDRAC 8 controller

Comment: I'm wrong "Information for all the storage devices connected to the system are not displayed and OpenManage Storage Management displays more storage devices that iDRAC. Why? iDRAC displays information for only the Comprehensive Embedded Management (CEM) supported devices."  Did you now there were 21 different versions for iDRAC8, BTW?

Answer (score 0):

The server was set up not to use raid and as such was not "hot swap" so I needed to go into system setup -> device managment and "make the disk 'non raid'".